# RabbitMQ reprocess deadletter queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I was looking for a way to take items from a rabbit deadletter queue and reprocess them back into the queue from which them came.  Is there a built in way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can consume messages from DLX (actually, from DLQ) the same way like from usual queue.

What you proposed (to get message from DLQ and publish it to queue it was originally deadlettered from) may lead (and it usually does) to message cycling.

Best-practice way is to process deadlettered messages in some separate way or do not deadletter them at all.

Comment: in cases where there is nothing wrong with the message but there was an error in processing (such as lost connections, etc) it would be handy the re-send in the messages and attempt re-processing.  I agree that if the dead letter fed everything back automatically that it would cause an infinite loop in most cases.

Comment: Use message acknowledge to prevent message lose in case of consumer unexpected failure.

Comment: Zaq, we nack the failures so that they don't get stuck in the queue forever.  I like your concept, we'd just need to make sure that things that should truly get nacked are, and things that can be re-tried stay.

Comment: Sure, it's all up to you. The solution really depends on your app requirement.

Comment: Anyone have examples of reprocessing? I have the DL exchange and queue set up and NAQ from my consumer places messages in the DLQ. I need an example of timed (say - after 5 min in the DLQ) to attempt reprocess.

Answer (score 0):

I I didn't find a built in way to do this so I created my own small solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.v0_9_1;

namespace RabbitMQReprocessDeadLetter
{
    public class RabbitReprocessor
    {
        private readonly IModel _model;
        private readonly string _deadLetterQueueName;
        private const ushort FetchSize = 10;
        private const string ConsumerName = "DeadLetterReprocessor";

        public RabbitReprocessor(IConnection rabbitConnection, string deadLetterQueueName)
        {
            _deadLetterQueueName = deadLetterQueueName;
            _model = rabbitConnection.CreateModel();
        }

        public void StartConsuming(CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = null)
        {
            // Configure the Quality of service for the model. Below is how what each setting means.
            // BasicQos(0="Dont send me a new message untill I’ve finshed",  _fetchSize = "Send me N messages at a time", false ="Apply to this Model only")
            _model.BasicQos(0, FetchSize, false);

            var queueingBasicConsumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(_model);
            _model.BasicConsume(_deadLetterQueueName, false, ConsumerName, queueingBasicConsumer);

            while (true)
            {
                if (cancellationTokenSource != null && cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var e = queueingBasicConsumer.Queue.Dequeue(); // blocking call
                var deathProperties = (List<object>) e.BasicProperties.Headers["x-death"];
                var prop = (Dictionary<string, object>)deathProperties.Single();
                var queueAsByteArray = (byte[])prop["queue"];
                var queueName = queueAsByteArray.ConvertToString();
                var data = e.Body;
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", queueName, data.Deserialize<long>());
                }
                // ReSharper disable once EmptyGeneralCatchClause
                catch { }
                SendMessageToQueue(queueName, data);
                _model.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// delivery the message directly into the queue from which it came.
        /// 
        /// You may want to put it back into an exchange instead of a queue.
        /// </summary>
        private void SendMessageToQueue(string queueName, byte[] messageBytes)
        {
            const string exchangeName = "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queueName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("queueName");
            }
            if (messageBytes == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("messageBytes");
            }
            var basicProperties = new BasicProperties
            {
                DeliveryMode = 2//2 = durable
            };
            _model.BasicPublish(exchangeName, queueName, basicProperties, messageBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

The full solution can be found here:

https://github.com/jayhilden/RabbitMQReprocessDeadLetter